# Converting tag format in a XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to programming in XSLT and I'm trying to practice XML conversions.

I have an example XML with the following entry:

```
<concept id="Name" value="John"/>
```

I would like to change this to be only like this

```
<Name> John </Name>
```

How would I achieve this?

I have been looking at tutorials, but I can't find the information relating to this specific problem anywhere...

Comment: This is not a valid XML input. Your element needs a name. Example <Node id="Name" value="John"/>

Comment: @Sebastien You're right. I have edited the original post with the missing name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it simply like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="concept">
      <xsl:element name="{@id}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxc

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works fine with the example I gave, but with the introduction of indents it fails to recognize the indented tags... I looked at other answers you gave and used some of the code in another solution to solve another problem I had... the indent problem persists though.

Comment: You can open a new question with your specific case.